# I have 4 week notice period and if I give notice today, how many more days (apart from today) do I need to work? [20 or 21?]

Tags: notice-period

This might be a very obvious question to answer. Today is 2nd May. I have a 4 week notice period. HR told me that notice period starts the day after tomorrow. (fine, this is consistent with what the internet told me)

So it is 4 weeks from 3rd May - I take that to mean you work 4 weeks from tomorrow. i.e. the last day will be 30th but HR team told me that it will be the 31st! (i.e. by my understanding, your notice period starts on a Wednesday, your last day is a Tuesday, but he says last day is Wednesday)

I just want to check if this is standard.

For instance, I see from this post

[Manager making me work extra post-notice (UK—Scotland)](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/186014/manager-making-me-work-extra-post-notice-uk-scotland)

that the guy gives notice on a Wednesday and his last notice day is Wednesday as I would have expected.

Comment: You say today is May 2nd, and HR said it starts the day after tomorrow, which would be the 4th. Later you say it starts on the 3rd. Knowing when it starts is the first question you need to ask.

Comment: Both things (notice period not starting at the day you give notice AND notice period not actually being 4 weeks) seems very weird to me. That is either something UK specific, something specific to your contract (what does it say?) or HR is just clueless (equally likely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need to work until 30th May.  If your HR team don't agree, you'll need to decide how much you value being right over being accommodating over a single extra (paid) day.

If you give notice during working hours today (2nd May), close of business 30th May is 20 full working days later.  You could draw out a calendar in an email to demonstrate this to your HR contact.  However, unless you have some other pressing commitment for 31st May, it'll could be less hassle you to just take up their suggestion that you work one extra day instead, taking you up to the end of the month.

If you show small flexibility you'll likely simplify their calculations for payroll and holidays due.  (If the person you're dealing with can't work out when is 20 days from now, imagine the debates you'll have about their pro-rata calculations for salary or holidays.)  Also, if your new employer makes a reference check, it'll do no harm if your current HR are feeling well-inclined towards you for the rest of the month.

Comment: This is indeed the case. The HR person was wrong. I got an automatic email saying my last date was the 30th. I wanted to work til the 31st to make sure I wont get prorated for benefits because I had enough holidays left anyway. In the end, I don't it made any difference anyway.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience - the moment you hit send is when your notice period starts.

Sometimes there are caveats - e.g. 'during business hours' - so if you resign at 9 pm at night, it's reasonable that it isn't 'actioned' until the next business day.

The real question is though - do you have any reason why you need to finish by a set date?

Comment: The reason is that I did not want to be prorated for benefits (if there is such a thing) because I had enough leave remaining. The last day was the 30th.